# Why the second "if" is not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to populate a view and I am writing the code of this view. The code:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tituloView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var txtTitulo: String?
var txt1: String?
var imageView: UIImageView?
var img1: String?
var txt2: String?
var texto2: String?
var imageView2: UIImageView?
var img2: String?
var txt3: String?
var img3: String?
var txt4: String?
var img4: String?

var arrayHeights: [Int] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tituloView.text = txtTitulo
    tituloView.textAlignment = .Center
    tituloView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 40)

    scrollView.zoomScale = 1

    var paragraphStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

    var attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: txt1!,
        attributes: [
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle1,
            NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)
        ])

    let texto1 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(154, -55, 697, 200))
    texto1.attributedText = attributedString1
    texto1.numberOfLines = 0
    texto1.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 28)
    texto1.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    texto1.sizeToFit()

    scrollView.addSubview(texto1)

    let imagem = UIImage(named: img1!)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: imagem)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 320, y: texto1.frame.size.height, width: 400, height: 250)
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    if (txt2 != nil) {

        var paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle2.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

        var attributedString2 = NSAttributedString(string: txt2!,
            attributes: [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle2,
                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)
            ])

        let texto2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(164, imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height + 20, 697, 200))
        texto2.attributedText = attributedString2
        texto2.numberOfLines = 0
        texto2.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 28)
        texto2.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        texto2.sizeToFit()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + texto2.frame.size.height + 20)


        scrollView.addSubview(texto2)

        if (img2 != nil) {

            let imagem2 = UIImage(named: img2!)
            let imageView2 = UIImageView(image: imagem2)
            imageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 320, y: texto2.frame.origin.y + texto2.frame.size.height, width: 400, height: 250)
            imageView2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + imageView2.frame.size.height + texto2.frame.size.height + 20)

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView2)

        } else {

            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height)

        }

    }

    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true

}


}
```

The problem is: if the img2 is nil, this code is not executed and my scrollView is not set properly:

```
var paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle2.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

        var attributedString2 = NSAttributedString(string: txt2!,
            attributes: [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle2,
                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)
            ])

        let texto2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(164, imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height + 20, 697, 200))
        texto2.attributedText = attributedString2
        texto2.numberOfLines = 0
        texto2.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 28)
        texto2.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        texto2.sizeToFit()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + texto2.frame.size.height + 20)


        scrollView.addSubview(texto2)
```

Why is this happening? If I img2 is not nil, the code runs with no problems. I added a println to see if the code inside the if statements were executed, and it was.

All infos (txtTitulo, txt1, imageView, txt2....) are being sent by another View Controller through a segue.

This view, the DetailViewController was created in StoryBoard with a label and a scrollView, the rest was added programmatically as you can see here.

I am sorry if this problem might seem too easy, but this is my first iOS app. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code.

Comment: You are not setting `img2` anywhere, so it's `nil`. If you don't want it to be `nil`, assign it a value.

Comment: @Sulthan I want it to be nil when I am not passing the image path. The problem here is that when this happens, I mean, when the img2 is nil, the         scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + texto2.frame.size.height + 20) never gets executed. See what I am saying?

Comment: @FernandoMarins If `txt2 != nil` then one of the `if (img2 != nil)` branches will always get executed. If you think it doesn't, you are checking it wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, you said:

> The problem here is that when this happens, I mean, when the img2 is
>   nil, the

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, 
  texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + 
  texto2.frame.size.height + 20)
```

> never gets executed. See what I am saying?

That code is not being executed because you told it not to. You have an if statement that says `if img2 != nil` and then a block of code that is only run if `img2 != nil`. Now you're asking why that code isn't executed when `img2 == nil`?

The answer is "Because that's how if statements work."

Comment: Thanks Duncan C, but when img2 == nil, txt2 may be not, which in this case, isn't. But when img2 == nil and txt2 !=, I want scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(texto1.frame.size.width, 
  texto1.frame.size.height + imageView.frame.size.height + 
  texto2.frame.size.height + 20)  to be executed.

Comment: It's getting executed, but then the 'else' block of the second if immediately sets scrollView.contentSize to something else.

Follow the code through with the debugger and you'll see what's going on.